# How to get the object from HttpActionResult Ok method (Web Api)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm learning some Web Api basics and I want to return and pass an object by `Ok(object)`. Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var someString = "";
    return Ok(someString);
}
```

Now I want to test this method and to assert if the returned string from this Get() method is the same as expected. I Guess will look something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGet()
{
    IHttpActionResult result = controller.Get();
    Assert.AreEqual("", result.??);
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936892/how-do-i-unit-test-web-api-action-method-when-it-returns-ihttpactionresult) question but the best answer is explaining how to validate the `HttpStatusCode`, not the passed object.

Comment: Rather than testing that the result is exactly equal to something, what do you care about in the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. Instead of trying to test if the passing object is valid, I will just insert some postconditions and depending on them, I will return different `HttpActionResults`.Thank you so much.

Comment: actually, there are cases that testing the returned result makes sense.

Comment: @KhanhTO Give an example.

Comment: For example: when you test a factory method, you need to test whether the returned object is of the expected type. There are countless cases where testing returned result makes sense, this is just one example.

Answer (score 47):

You can access the returned string by casting the result to `OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>` and accessing its `Content` property.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGet()
{
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Get();
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>;
    Assert.AreEqual("", contentResult.Content);
}
```

Example code from: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: @CodeCaster: updated. But sometimes I think the code is simple and self-explanatory.