# Get object from IHttpActionResult response c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using and Web API to perform some task, and when the task is finished the API return me a object in the OK method.

The code:

```
[Route("upload")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFormData()
{
    //Create the object
    var blob = new BlobUploadModel();

    //Do some tasks
    ...

    //Return
    return Ok(blob);
}
```

How can I get this blob object in the response which, I think, should be a IHttpActionResult?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting JSON to be returned from the API when you call this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API will serialize your instance of BlobUploadModel into the MIME type specified in the client request `Accept:` header.   The serialized blob will then be attached to the response body.

Your client that calls this action will need to deserialize the contents of the response body back to a BlobUploadModel.  JSON.Net is a great library for serialization/deserialization between JSON objects and CLR objects.  To deserialize a JSON response back to a BlobUploadModel using JSON.Net you can use the following:

```
 var blob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlobUploadModel>(responseBody);
```

Keep in mind that your client project will need to know what a BlobUploadModel is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got some further questions. If the object is serialized into XML format, will the JSON library still work? And How can I get this responseBody as a string? For now, I got the response as a var, should I just cast it to a string?

Comment: If you're working with XML, you'll want to use an XML library like System.Xml.Serialization.  This link shows a good example of deserialization with this library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx.  Regarding how to get the response as a string, it will depend on your HTTP client and how you're using it, but in most cases it will already be a string, so var will simply evaluate to string at runtime.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002936/how-to-get-the-object-from-httpactionresult-ok-method-web-api/30002975#30002975