# Xunit test IHttpActionResult web api 2 function for custom message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, xunit.net

I refactor my web api functions (to take advantage of web api 2 changes) but can't figure out how to refactor my xUnit tests testing for custom exception messages.

I refactor this:

```
[Route("resetpassword"), HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ResetPassword([FromBody] ResetPasswordRequest request)
{
  try
  {
    var resetPermission = _userPasswordResetRequestRepository.GetByToken(request.Token);

    if (resetPermission.Expires < DateTimeOffset.Now)
      throw new Exception("Token expired");

    _userPasswordRepository.SetPassword(resetPermission.UserId, request.Password);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Request received");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
  }
}
```

to this (return type changed to IHttpActionResult, and return statements changed):

```
[Route("resetpassword"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ResetPassword([FromBody] ResetPasswordRequest request)
{
  try
  {
    var resetPermission = _userPasswordResetRequestRepository.GetByToken(request.Token);

    if (resetPermission.Expires < DateTimeOffset.Now)
      throw new Exception("Token expired");

    _userPasswordRepository.SetPassword(resetPermission.UserId, request.Password);

    return Ok("Request received");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return InternalServerError(ex);
  }
}
```

My failing xUnit test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(-10, true)]
[InlineData(10, false)]
public void IfTokenExpired_ShouldReturnError(int expireOffsetMinutes, bool shouldBeExpired)
{
  ...
  // Assert
  Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode); // <-- fail
  if (shouldBeExpired)
    Assert.Equal("Token expired.", response.ContentString()); // <-- fail
}
```

How do I test:

- for a correct header? Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
- for a specific string in the custom exception message? Assert.Equal("Token expired.", response.ContentString());

Comment: What kind of response does an exception generate? Just cast the response to that (for example OkNegotiatedContentResult for HTTP 200)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this answer: [How do I unit test web api action method when it returns IHttpActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936892/how-do-i-unit-test-web-api-action-method-when-it-returns-ihttpactionresult)

However, **return Ok("Request received");** returns **OkNegotiatedContentResult** and not **OkResult** as suggested.

So this:

```
Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
Assert.Equal("Token expired", response.ContentString())
```

I changed into this:

```
Assert.IsType<OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>>(response);
Assert.Equal(((OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>)response).Content, "Token expired");
```