# How to check 200 ok using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, assert

I have created a web API that returns 200 ok response.

```
 public IHttpActionResult get()
 {
    return Ok();
 }
```

Also, I have created a test project using the NUnit framework.

```
var controller = new StatusController();
var result= controller.level0() as OkNegotiatedContentResult<object>;
IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.level0();
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, actionResult);
```

But i got error like this

```
Expected: OK
  But was:  <System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult>
```

When I am trying to debug the 'actionResult' variable, it contains one error

```
Request = '((System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult)actionResult).Request' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

How do I check my http status code ?

Comment: see this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/19937421/5514820

Comment: Example from above link uses xunit framework

Comment: @AbdulManaf This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: In your example, controller has `get()` action. In the test you call `level0()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the provided controller you appear to be casting the result to the wrong type.

`Ok()` returns an instance of `OkResult`

check the return type to verify that action under test behaves as expected.

```
//Arrange
var controller = new StatusController();

//Act
IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.get();

//Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkResult>(actionResult);
```

Reference [Unit Testing Controllers in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)